# Convert raw string to string

Tags: flutter, dart

If I print a raw string e.g.

```dart
String raw = r'\n\n\n';
print('Output: $raw');
// Output: \n\n\n
```

I gets exactly these characters. But what do I have to do to get three empty lines, i.e. unescaping the raw string?

I could replace the characters one by one with

```dart
String unRaw = raw.replaceAll(r'\n', '\n');
```

but unfortunately I'd have to do that with every escape sequence, which is error-prone.

Context: I get the raw string from a user via a textfield and want to interpret it as a normal string.

Comment: What do you mean by "interpreted as normal string"? Do you have any warning/error?

Comment: By "interpreted as normal string" I mean that Dart interprets the special characters of the String as special characters and not as normal letters. For example, when I print the raw string I actually get the characters '\n\n\n' instead of three empty lines, but I want these empty lines.

No there are no warnings or errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no direct method to do it, check [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/9190). There is a third-party [package](https://pub.dev/packages/strings) that claims to do it.

However, I think there is workaround that can be done is using a `jsonDecoder` for your case here.

`jsonDecoder` can decode strings too, hence construct a raw json, then decode it to get your string.

Example:

```
import 'dart:convert';

main(){
    String value = r'a\nb';
    print(value); // prints raw string
    value = jsonDecode(r'{ "data":"'+value+r'"}')['data']; // converted to escaped string
    print(value); // prints a & b in different lines
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: if value include " ,  jsonDecode will thow error